# If $1=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)$ for $x,y\in A_{sa}$ then $x$ and $y$ commute by spectral theory

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am trying to understand example 1.1.13 given in C*-algebras and their automorphism groups by Pedersen:

The part that I do not understand is the following:
For $1=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)$ where $x,y$ are self-adjoint elements of the $C^*$-algebra A of norm $\leq 1$ and 1 is the unit of $A$. They claim that it then follows by spectral theory that $x$ and $y$ commute and that $x=y=1$.

**My question**: how does commutativity follow?

Comment: I missed a detail thanks, the norm of $x$ and $y$ should be $\leq 1$. I edited the post.

Comment: If this was not a general $C^*$-algebra, but the algebra of bounded operators on a Hilbert space, then you could use the associated quadratic form. For selfadjoint operators we have $$\Vert T\Vert=\sup_{\Vert \xi\Vert =1} \vert \langle \xi, T\xi\rangle\vert.$$ Thus, $\Vert x \Vert \leq 1$ implies that the quadratic form bounded by $1$. Hence, we get $$1=\langle \xi, 1\xi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\langle \xi, x\xi\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle \xi, y\xi \rangle \leq \frac{1}{2}\langle \xi, x\xi\rangle + \frac{1}{2}.$$ Thus, for any normalized $\xi$ we get $\langle \xi, x \xi\rangle =1$ and hence $x=1$

Comment: I know nothing about $C^*$-algebras, maybe there is a similar thing that you can use.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Every $C^\ast$-algebra can be faithfully represented on a Hilbert space.

Comment: @MaoWao Ohh cool! I didn't know that. Does this theorem have a name? That sounds quite handy

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes, that's the Gelfand-Naimark theorem (or the noncommutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem, since some people also call the basic representation theorem for commutative $C^\ast$-algebras Gelfand-Naimark theorem).

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks a lot! Looks quite fun.

Comment: Fair enough. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$x+y=2.$$ So $y=2-x$, and then it is obvious that $x$ and $y$ commute. you don't even need them to be selfadjoint for this to hold.

For the other part, from $y=2-x$ we get that $\|x\|\leq1$ and $\|2-x\|\leq1$. The first inequality gives us that $\sigma(x)\subset[-1,1]$, while the second one gives us $\sigma(x)\subset [1,3]$. Thus $\sigma(x)=\{1\}$.

Comment: Not that it is wrong, but it seems like a rather complicated way of showing that $x$ and $2-x$ commute.

Comment: You are so right. Missing the trees for the forest, I guess :D

Comment: Quite neat :) (+1)